# How to get rid of the auto generated j_idt ID in composite component

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I'm using below composite component:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="inputId" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <h:panelGrid id="myTableId">
        <h:inputText id="#{cc.attrs.inputId}" value="..." />
        ...
    </h:panelGrid>
</composite:implementation>
```

And I'm using it in my form as below:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <myCompositeComp:test inputId="myInputTextBoxId" />
<h:form>
```

I've verified the view source for the page and this is how it is generated:

```
<table id="myForm:j_idt90:myTableId">
    ...
    <input type="text" id="myForm:j_idt90:myInputTextBoxId" />
</table>
```

How can I get rid of `j_idt90` here? Is it the `id` of my composite component? I read from one of BalusC post that this issue will get fixed if I declare `id` as static. But I'm not able to identify the place to declare it in my code. Also can I assume `<h:panelGrid>` is a kind of `UINamingContainer`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is the id of your composite component, `<h:panelGrid>` is not a `UINaminContainer` but the composite component is (it has to be, otherwise you would have duplicate IDs if you use it several times inside the same form for example).

Why do you need to get rid of the ID? You can set it yourself if that solves your problem:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <myCompositeComp:test id="myComp" attr1="" attr2="" />
<h:form>
```

the genereated html should look like this:

```
<table id="myForm:myComp:myTableId">
        ....
        <input type="text" id="myForm:myComp:myInputTextBoxId"
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working now. I was under impression that a composite component will have no ID on its own.